# How Can I automatically download a Transcript (VTT file) of a video using a Logic APP?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-cognitive-services

I have indexed few videos into the videoindexer.ai using a logic app. But I was wondering, is there a way to use Logic app to download the transcript file that are in a VTT format and place them in a Onedrive folder? Not seeing documentation on how this can done through a logic app.

**Azure Function:**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;

namespace TranscriptVtt
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

            // Request headers
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-client-request-id", "");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "{subscription key}");

            // Request parameters
            queryString["indexId"] = "{string}";
            queryString["format"] = "Vtt";
            queryString["language"] = "{string}";
            queryString["accessToken"] = "{string}";
            var uri = "https://api.videoindexer.ai/{location}/Accounts/{accountId}/Videos/{videoId}/Captions?" + queryString;
            var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            return new OkObjectResult("VTT Processed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a connector to Video Indexer for LogicApps, which has a 'Get Captions' operation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/videoindexer-v2/#get-video-captions

Comment: @NicolasR I think I got it work, but I have one question. When it downloads the VTT file into the "output" folder, why is the name of the file with numbers like: 27352-Caprion.vtt? How can we make the file name same as when we are indexing the video? For example if we indexed a video with the  name "test.mp4" the VTT should be "test-Caption.vtt"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a quick demo by doing the following (and it's working):

- LogicApp #1 for video upload: triggers one OneDrive "Input" folder, and upload video to Video Indexer for indexing
- LogicApp #2 for result collection: http trigger which will be called by indexing, then get the captions and create a file in a OneDrive "Output" folder.

The trick is the fact that, as described in `Upload Video` operation of Video Indexer (see [here](https://api-portal.videoindexer.ai/docs/services/Operations/operations/Upload-Video?)), you can add a callback:

[image: Upload video documentation]

As you can see, this callback will have the id of the video added in the query string.

So in your LogicApp #2, use this `id` on the `Get Video Captions` action of Video Indexer:

[image: Implementation detail 1]

The expression to get the id is `triggerOutputs()['queries']['id']`.

Then you just have to copy to your output:

[image: Implementation detail 2]

I used a naming based on the video id: `concat(triggerOutputs()['queries']['id'],'-Captions.vtt')`

And it works:
[image: Result]

To get a better implementation, you should add a check to filter callbacks due to face detections mentioned above. This can be done by filtering on 'State' query string value.

Here is the code of my LogicApp #2 (with a few hidden fields):

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Create_file": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": "@body('Get_Video_Captions')",
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['onedrive']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/datasets/default/files",
                    "queries": {
                        "folderPath": "/LogicAppsDemo/VideoIndexing/Output",
                        "name": "@{concat(triggerOutputs()['queries']['id'],'-Captions.vtt')}"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Get_Video_Captions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                    "contentTransfer": {
                        "transferMode": "Chunked"
                    }
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Get_Account_Access_Token": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['videoindexer-v2']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/auth/@{encodeURIComponent('##VI-REGION##')}/Accounts/@{encodeURIComponent('##VI-ACCOUNT##')}/AccessToken",
                    "queries": {
                        "allowEdit": false
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Get_Video_Captions": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['videoindexer-v2']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/@{encodeURIComponent('##VI-REGION##')}/Accounts/@{encodeURIComponent('##VI-ACCOUNT##')}/Videos/@{encodeURIComponent(triggerOutputs()['queries']['id'])}/Captions",
                    "queries": {
                        "accessToken": "@body('Get_Account_Access_Token')",
                        "format": "vtt",
                        "language": "English"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Get_Account_Access_Token": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "method": "POST",
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {

            "value": {
                "onedrive": { ... },
                "videoindexer-v2": { ... }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, your use-case is almost described in a blog post from Microsoft (here they are getting the index, not the captions): https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/logic-apps-flow-connectors-will-make-automating-video-indexer-simpler-than-ever/

Comment: could please expand the "When a HTTP request is received" tab? I wanted to see what you have added in the HTTP POST URL. Thank you.

Comment: I think I got it work, but I have one question. When it downloads the VTT file into the "output" folder, why is the name of the file with numbers like: 27352-Caprion.vtt? How can we make the file name same as when we are indexing the video? For example if we indexed a video with the name "test.mp4" the VTT should be "test-Caption.vtt"

Comment: I added nothing in the HTTP trigger, as the callback from Video Indexer is automatically adding the needed fields (and I can't set the payload for this callback). For the output file name, you can put what you want, it's in the "Create file" operation, field "File Name". If you want to use your video name, you have to add a step "Get Video Index" before to get this field https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/videoindexer-v2/#get-video-index

Comment: Could please show me, how can I take the VTT files once they are in the "output" folder, and send those file as outlook email attachments to a specific person? So that whenever, there is a new VTT file in the "output" folder, the files get sent as an attachment to that person.

Comment: Manually, or automatically?

Comment: automatically send an email when there is a new VTt file in the output folder.

Comment: is that possible?

Comment: Sure, you just have to create another app which trigger is a OneDrive trigger, when a file is created on the output folder. And a 2nd step which is the one to send the email (there is an outlook action for that)

Comment: but how can you send the vtt as an attachment when you are sending the email?

Comment: The file is the output of your trigger so you have it. In your outlook step, map it to "Attachments" (available through "Add new parameter" in your Send email v2 step from Outlook)

Answer (score 0):

Directly using Logic App connector I don't think it's possible, but you can get it directly using REST API. Perform a Request, and according to the response, add a new task which will be the onedrive connector:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/onedrive/

REST API:

```
curl -v -X GET "https://api.videoindexer.ai/{location}/Accounts/{accountId}/Videos/{videoId}/Captions?indexId={string}&format=Vtt&language={string}&accessToken={string}"
-H "x-ms-client-request-id: "
-H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: {subscription key}"

--data-ascii "{body}"
```

EDIT: 
The equivalent int c#. You'll need to use it on a web server (Azure Functions would be great):

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;

namespace CSHttpClientSample
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            MakeRequest();
            Console.WriteLine("Hit ENTER to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static async void MakeRequest()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

            // Request headers
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-client-request-id", "");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "{subscription key}");

            // Request parameters
            queryString["indexId"] = "{string}";
            queryString["format"] = "Vtt";
            queryString["language"] = "{string}";
            queryString["accessToken"] = "{string}";
            var uri = "https://api.videoindexer.ai/{location}/Accounts/{accountId}/Videos/{videoId}/Captions?" + queryString;

            var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        }
    }
}
```

You need to pass the response to your Onedrive task in your workflow.

https://api-portal.videoindexer.ai/docs/services/operations/operations/Get-video-captions

Comment: Hi, I partially understand what you are saying but I don't understand the ECHO example because I am not familiar  with echo. Can this all be done in .NEt C#? . Also what exactly do you mean by "add a new new task" is this part of  Logic app?

Comment: I have a question. I have taken the sample code that you have provided and inserted that into an Azure function triggered by HTTP. Would you please take a look at the function and let me know if it's accurate or anything needs to be changed? Thank you.

Comment: you need to insert the subscription key / account id, etc ... the function is right because it's from Microsoft`s official doc. You'd better start with the curl (make it work) then, switch to the c# code